# Centering heading text with button toolbar in Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the `.btn-toolbar` class in Bootstrap3 to place buttons on both sides of some heading text. I need the heading text to be centered, so I am using the `.text-center` class.

The text indeed gets centered relative to the space between the buttons. But I'd like the text to be centered on the page itself, just like the text in the `main` section below the heading in the example below.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Here's an example to hopefully illustrate this better:

```css
h2 {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class='btn-toolbar pull-left'>
  <div class='btn-group'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Button Text</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Button Text</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
  <div class='btn-group'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Button Text</button>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Text</h2>
<div class="main">
  This text is centered on the page.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using float to position your toolbar, you can try using `position: absolute;`

Have a look at the following code. Does this help?

```css
h2 {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* New CSS for toolbar */

.my-toolbar{ position: relative;}
.my-toolbar .btn-toolbar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
}
.my-toolbar .btn-toolbar.left{
  left: 0;
}
.my-toolbar .btn-toolbar.right{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="my-toolbar">
<div class='btn-toolbar left'>
    <div class='btn-group'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Button Text</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Button Text</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='btn-toolbar right'>
    <div class='btn-group'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Button Text</button>
    </div>
</div>
<h2>Text</h2>
</div>
<div class="main">
This text is centered on the page.
</div>
```